# Need to be able to check xlsx or .csv for bad characters

Tags: excel, magento, utf-8, export-to-csv

from Excel to .csv with UTF8 encoding -- I did a search here and read quite a few answers but mine hasn't specifically been answered that I see. I need a Mac equivalent to Notepad++ -- I save Excel imports for Magento as .csv and need to convert as text (UTF-8?) and then check and make sure no characters will cause problems with the import, (like hyphens, accents, curly quotes) since it won't import at all with errors.
So - a coworker uses Notepad++ and have a Mac and haven't found any app that will search and replace bad characters.  Thanks in advance if someone can help.

Comment: Consider changing whatever generates the source .csv. It seems your team is too busy fixing the problem after the fact and not tackling the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Mac equivalent of Notepad++, you can actually install Notepad++ using app called [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) or [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/). This tutorial shows you how you can [install Notepad++ using WineBottler](https://mike.kronenberg.org/winebottler-how-to-install-notepad-on-a-mac/).

Just a word of caution, it is never the same experience as native Windows experience. But it gets the job done. Also, remember that the keyboard keys behave little differently on Mac, compared to Windows. (If you are not much keyboard-junkie, you don't have to worry about it).

If you are looking for Mac app, Mac's own **TextEdit** is a very accomplished Text Editor (much better than Windows strip-down Notepad).

Comment: Thanks Cricrazy - we've tried TextEdit - it doesn't seem to find the bad characters.

Comment: Your best option may be to add NPP using the Winebottler. You can also install windows on Mac using Free tool, `VirtualBox`!

Comment: Solution: I had to set up a pc at my station so hopefully that will help. We think Mac excel changes characters upon saving as a .csv.